# SQL query column with cookie data

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2

My cookie member names are the first and last name of the user with a space in between.  I'm trying to get the user ID from the row with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.users WHERE firstname IN('{$_COOKIE['member_name']}') AND lastname IN('{$_COOKIE['member_name']}')
```

I'm not getting any results from this, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  The LIKE operator isn't working either.

Comment: why on earth are you using `IN()`'s for?

Comment: so the first and last names are the same as the cookie name? I doubt that.

Comment: at best; use the `OR` operator. Hard to say what's what here really and what the db values are and the cookie value.

Comment: `IN()` looks at array of items

Comment: You're not going to get any solution(s) if you don't interact here. Post the cookie value and db schema/values. If you logged off, then don't expect a magic answer when you do get back. This post is about as clear as mud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why using IN() ?

i have try like this query, can work for my data

maybe you can check table column data type and output query SQL.

```
(root@localhost) [test]> select * from a;
+------+------+-------+
| team | type | value |
+------+------+-------+
| A    | 0    |    10 |
| A    | 1    |     5 |
| B    | 0    |    10 |
| B    | 0    |    10 |
| A    | 1    |    20 |
| B    | 1    |    20 |
+------+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

(root@localhost) [test]> select * from a where team in ('A') and type in ('0');
+------+------+-------+
| team | type | value |
+------+------+-------+
| A    | 0    |    10 |
+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```